# Can't integration the instagram login in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I got the problem with instagram integration I need to implement the instagram in my app I have created and registered the app and got client ID and secret ID, I copy the code and create the webview I got instagram login page but I can't login with instagram I don't know which point I am missing please help me to solve my issues. I got error "you are not sandbox user I am confused how to do the instagram login and sharing.

Here is my code

```
-(void)initialisation{

    self.title = @"Social Media Sharing";
    [self showButtonOnLeftWithImageName:@""];
    self.typeOfAuthentication = @"UNSIGNED";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    NSString* authURL = nil;

    if ([self.typeOfAuthentication isEqualToString:@"UNSIGNED"])
    {
        authURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=%@&DEBUG=True",
                   INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,
                   INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
                   INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI,
                   INSTAGRAM_SCOPE];

    }
    else
    {
        authURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=code&scope=%@&DEBUG=True",
                   INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,
                   INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
                   INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI,
                   INSTAGRAM_SCOPE];
    }


    [loginWebView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: authURL]]];
    [loginWebView setDelegate:self];
}




#pragma mark - Button Actions

-(void)backButtonAction:(UIButton *)backButton{

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}



- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return [self checkRequestForCallbackURL: request];
}

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [loginIndicator startAnimating];
   // loadingLabel.hidden = NO;
    [loginWebView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    loginWebView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.1 animations:^{
        //  loginWebView.alpha = 0.2;
    }];
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [loginIndicator stopAnimating];
  //  loadingLabel.hidden = YES;
    [loginWebView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    loginWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.1 animations:^{
        //loginWebView.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self webViewDidFinishLoad: webView];
}

- (BOOL) checkRequestForCallbackURL: (NSURLRequest*) request
{
    NSString* urlString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    if ([self.typeOfAuthentication isEqualToString:@"UNSIGNED"])
    {
        // check, if auth was succesfull (check for redirect URL)
        if([urlString hasPrefix: INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI])
        {
            // extract and handle access token
            NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString: @"#access_token="];
            [self handleAuth: [urlString substringFromIndex: range.location+range.length]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if([urlString hasPrefix: INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI])
        {
            // extract and handle code
            NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString: @"code="];
            [self makePostRequest:[urlString substringFromIndex: range.location+range.length]];
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;

}

-(void)makePostRequest:(NSString *)code
{

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=%@&code=%@",INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,INSTAGRAM_CLIENTSERCRET,INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI,code];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *requestData = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                        [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"]];
    [requestData setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [requestData setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [requestData setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [requestData setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestData returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    [self handleAuth:[dict valueForKey:@"access_token"]];

}

- (void) handleAuth: (NSString*) authToken
{
    NSLog(@"successfully logged in with Tocken == %@",authToken);

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Go through these links, may be you can get any solutions: 1.https://mindfiremobile.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/how-to-integrate-instagram-into-ios-application-and-share-photo-with-it/ 2.http://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2015/02/integrate-instagram-in-ios.html

Comment: thanks for the response . ukesh i follw the same tutorilas but i cant share and login

Comment: i got login page of instagram but it show this page is broken unavailable